# Is there is an app maker for the android?

Tags: android

Is there is for the android an app maker tool like the ones in the iPhone ?? tools that can help the developer to develop an application easily... especially for the general things and nothing new in it... like the GUI and the action listener... I mean the developer should care about how to implement the functionality rather than wasting his time in the Gui it self and the other stuff...

Answer (score 2):

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com

Comment: unfortunately, I heard that when I create app with a appinventor , I can't use the code again... I mean, I can't create the UI in appinventor and then create my own code and logic(coding)... If i use appinventor in a project, then I have to finish the whole project using it. am I right ?? I didn't use it at all, but this is what I heard about it.... Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Your project is saved online (as long as you don't delete it) and anytime you can log on to your account from anywhere and modify the app.

Comment: Yes.. u cant use app inventor for creating UI only and then get that to integrate with your control logic.

Comment: So, As i said before... if i use the appinventor in a project i should finish it with right ?? The question now is, does the appinventor really helpful ?? I think you can't make a great app with it, right ?? I need a tool to help me doing the job quickly and also I can do some functionality(using coding) ... Please don't tell me DroidDraw cause its not that much helpful... Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

[DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) is a GUI designer/editor that you can use to build your GUI.

Answer (score 1):

[AppFurnace](http://www.appfurnace.com) is a cloud-based app maker that allows you to publish to Android and iPhone - you can use your own JavaScript to program functionality, it's got a built-in GPS tool, as well as a GUI tool for the front-end.

(Disclaimer: I work for AppFurnace)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse plugin has fair bit of UI functionality. You could control most layout xml files through UI designer. (No Action listerners though)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Infinite Monkeys App Maker to [create Android Apps](http://www.infinitemonkeys.mobi) for business, community and other social groups. Any one can create app with this tool as no coding required and simply drag n drop functionality.